# How Do You Convert Math Symbols in Haskell?

Tags: plutus, haskell, plutus-core

So i heard you can use denotational semantics to write Haskell code using math notation for example `circle` in place of `.` to denote function composition. My question is in four parts:

1. how do I use/write this into my code?
2. how is the conversion between the two handled?
3. does this come with time or security concerns?
4. does this still compile to plutus-core correctly?

Answer (score 2):

By using `.` you are already using denotational semantic

> In computer science, denotational semantics (initially known as mathematical semantics or Scott–Strachey semantics) is an approach of formalizing the meanings of programming languages by constructing mathematical objects

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics))

in fact the `.` aims to emulate the [function composition operator in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) ( `∘`, used as `g  ∘  f` to indicate a function that acts as `g(f(x))` ).

with that being said there are still your question to answer to:

## how do I use/write this into my code?

in Haskell is as simple as:

```hs
circle :: ( b -> c ) -> ( a -> b ) -> ( a -> c )
circle = (.)
```

## how is the conversion between the two handled?

being Haskell lazy-evaluated, when you get to the point of calling

```hs
circle g f
```

it will be substituted to

```hs
(.) g f
```

which is equivalent to

```hs
g . f
```

## does this come with time or security concerns?

no security concerns, this is all handled by haskell.

## does this still compile to plutus-core correctly?

as long it is `{-# INLINEABLE circle #-}` it doesn't comes to my mind a reason why it wouldn't